# How should this limit superior from a proof of the Lebesgue Differentiation Theorem be interpreted?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

On page 104 of [Stein and Shakarchi's Real Analysis](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691113866), in their proof of the Lebesgue Differentiation Theorem, the following limit superior appears:

$$
\limsup_{m(B) \to 0,\,x \in B} \bigg\vert\frac{1}{m(B)}\int_B f(y)\,dy - f(x)\bigg\vert,
$$

where $f : \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ is an integrable function and $B$ is an open ball in $\mathbb{R}^d$. I understand what the limit superior of a sequence is and what the limit superior of a function is. I'm guessing that this limit superior is the limit superior of a function, but I'm not sure. How should this limit superior be interpreted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix $x$. For a given $\epsilon>0$, let 
$$
g(x,\epsilon):=\sup\left\{\bigg\vert\frac{1}{m(B)}\int_B f(y)\,dy - f(x)\bigg\vert: x\in B\hbox{ and } m(B)<\epsilon\right\}
$$
As $\epsilon$ decreases to $0$, $g(x,\epsilon)$ also decreases, to some limit. This limit is the $\limsup$ you seek. (I presume that $B$ is to be a ball.)